# How to pass default value to selected column name if null found with inner join with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that shows details of jobs. here I have check if null value found with inner join then pass with precondition.

Here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT   
    Jobs.EmailsSent,
    Jobs.SubscriberCount,
    Jobs.CompletedOn,
    Jobs.PreparedEmailID,
    Jobs.JobID,
    Jobs.CreatedOn,
    tbl_Categories.CategoryName,
    tbl_Email_master.Title,
    tbl_From_master.Name As FromUsername,
    tbl_User_master.Name AS CreatedBy 
FROM
    Jobs 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Email_master ON Jobs.PreparedEmailID = tbl_Email_master.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_From_master ON Jobs.FromuserID = tbl_From_master.Id
                    AND  tbl_Email_master.FromUser = tbl_From_master.Id 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Categories ON tbl_Categories.Id = Jobs.CategoryID
                   OR (tbl_Categories.Id IS NOT NULL
                       AND Jobs.CategoryID IS NULL) 
-- here pass default value like ALL if Jobs.CategoryID found NULL
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_User_master ON Jobs.UserID = tbl_User_master.Id
                    AND tbl_Email_master.user_id = tbl_User_master.Id
                    AND tbl_From_master.user_id = tbl_User_master.Id
                    AND tbl_Categories.user_id = tbl_User_master.Id
WHERE 
    Jobs.JobID = '7'
```

Can we do with this?

**--------------------------------updated--------------------------------**

with this ans :

```
INNER JOIN tbl_Categories ON tbl_Categories.Id = coalesce(Jobs.CategoryID,tbl_Categories.Id) OR (tbl_Categories.Id IS NOT NULL AND coalesce(Jobs.CategoryID,tbl_Categories.Id)=tbl_Categories.Id)
```

i have retrieving row like :

[image]

now I just only want raws/raw with default category value ALL.

```
--------------------------------as text----------------------------------


                    CATEGORY NAME 
0   44  NULL    Friends
0   44  NULL    Family Relatives
0   44  NULL    Business Clients
0   44  NULL    Corporate Profiles
0   44  NULL    test
0   44  NULL    Infisms Clients
0   44  NULL    Infisms Clients
```

here i just want to return row/rows with Category Name as ALL.

Comment: your example queries are too long

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

```
...tbl_Categories.Id = coalesce(Jobs.CategoryID,tbl_Categories.Id) OR 
(tbl_Categories.Id IS NOT NULL 
                   AND coalesce(Jobs.CategoryID,tbl_Categories.Id)=tbl_Categories.Id)
```

assuming `tbl_Categories.Id` is a `non-null` column

Comment: by putting this statement it's gives me error like : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: @shalingajjar yes, fixed now.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ALL' to data type int.

Comment: @shalingajjar but the question suggests `ALL` literal, then that column's data type is `int` and an integer value should be used as argument, such as `coalesce(Jobs.CategoryID,0)=0`

Comment: please just read question again when first line of select statement I retrieved tbl_Categories.CategoryName if NO NULL found if NULL found then just pass literal vaue as ALL

Comment: @shalingajjar well, please check now (I think I understood what you've meant now)

Comment: @shalingajjar Can you share it as text please, from the place I've been cannot see the picture sharings.

Comment: @shalingajjar sorry, I couldn't understand from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
INNER JOIN 
tbl_Categories ON tbl_Categories.Id = isnull(Jobs.CategoryID, tbl_Categories.Id)
```

Comment: simple, I got no of rows with different category names and I want it pass all category names as ALL.